# Tutorial website platform

Tags: web-apps, wordpress, web

Googling "tutorial website platform" finds a lot of tutorials on how to make websites or how to make tutorials on existing websites.

But I'm trying to find a platform for creating a tutorial website.

That means I want to create a tutorial, share my knowledge and show it publicly on the internet.

Right now I write the tutorial in Wordpress.com because it's free and and it works well but there are some hardships like a wysiwyg without table support and no automatical navigation between previous and next article.

I wonder if anyone created something similar like Wordpress.com specifically for tutorial creators? If not exactly like Wordpress.com then maybe something similar?

Comment: Something like Instructables or learn.adafruit.com?

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to look at one of the Wiki systems like [dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki#)

Use cases include: Corporate Knowledge Base, Software manual, etc.

You can see other [wiki software here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) also, together with a specific contributed module for it, which IMO might be a possible implementation of what you're looking for, if not more: the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) (*) module. Here are some details about it (from its project page):

> Answers enables the implementation of a Question & Answer system in a Drupal site. Users can post questions and other users can answer them.

Head over to its project page for more details.

At its core, this module exists of 2 typical content types:

- Question.
- Answers.

The "Best Answer" submodule can be used so that the question author can "accept" one of the answers as the best one. And you could make the Rules module to either trigger all sorts of subsequent things to happen "when an answer gets marked as best answer", or to add all sorts of validations when posting an answer (or question).

The Answers module comes with integrations with other modules such as the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and the [Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module and supports voting.

## Demo

Have a look at the (new) [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/module/answers) of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module. This link shows various menu options within the block with title ***Answers Menu***, i.e.:

- **Questions** (= a view):

  - **All**: of all existing questions (= default tab).
  - **Answered**: all questions which have a "best" (= accepted) answer (= sub-tab).
  - **Unanswered**: all questions which do not yet have a "best" (= accepted) answer (= sub-tab).
- **Answers** (= a view): lists all existing answers for any of the existing questions and which does not (yet) have any submenu options (implemented as tabs).
- **Rankings** (= a view): contains a list of users with their actual ranking (= reputation points implemented via user points), and with each user a link to either the questions or answers from that user.
- **Ask Question**: to post a new question (the equivalent of `node/add/question`), which is only shown for authenticated users though.

These views also use the [dataTables](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) format, but you could easily replace that with any views display format you'd want. And because of the search box that comes with dataTables, there is no need for extra menu links to search within questions, answers or rankings.

In the context of this questions here, you may also want to look at the answer to "[Does the Answers module support markdown text?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/78)", which explains that this module indeed does support it.

<sup>(*) Disclosure: I'm a (co-)maintainer of this module.</sup>